# How do I remove kubuntu-full and all it's applications?

Tags: kubuntu, uninstall

I'm running 12.04 - I installed kubuntu to try it out and realized that with all the bloatware applications that I didn't want it anymore - I was able to uninstall the `kubuntu-desktop` but there are still packages left over... How can I make sure I get rid of EVERYTHING Kubuntu installed - even the kde leftovers?

Here's some of what's left when I ran `sudo apt-get autoremove kde` then "tab" it displayed this:

> kdeaccessibility              kdepim-runtime kdeadmin
>   kde-runtime kde-baseapps                  kde-runtime-data
>   kde-baseapps-bin              kdesdk-dolphin-plugins kde-baseapps-data
>   kde-style-oxygen kde-config-cron               kdesudo kde-config-gtk 
>   kdeutils kde-config-touchpad           kde-wallpapers
>   kdegames-card-data            kde-wallpapers-default
>   kdegames-card-data-extra      kde-window-manager kde-icons-mono
>   kde-window-manager-common kdelibs5-data                 kde-workspace
>   kdelibs5-plugins              kde-workspace-bin kdelibs-bin
>   kde-workspace-data kdemultimedia-kio-plugins
>   kde-workspace-data-extras kdenetwork
>   kde-workspace-kgreet-plugins kdenetwork-filesharing
>   kde-zeroconf kdepasswd                     kdf kdepim-kresources
>   kdm kdepimlibs-kio-plugins        kdoctools

Those are all installed by kubuntu... correct?  I just want to go back to my Ubuntu 12.04LTS with Gnome2-classic and without all the kubuntu extras.

I started it off by just removing unnecessary apps that came with kubuntu-full - then realized I didnt want the whole thing at all and uninstalled kubuntu-full but it still says I have these as well:

> alex@griever:~$ sudo apt-get --purge remove kubuntu-
>   kubuntu-debug-installer           kubuntu-netbook-default-settings
>   kubuntu-default-settings          kubuntu-notification-helper
>   kubuntu-firefox-installer         kubuntu-web-shortcuts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove those as well - kubuntu-full is a metapackage, installing it will include it's recommends - uninstalling it does not unfortunately. Only way is to remove the packages as you are doing.

More information on metapackages can be found here - https://askubuntu.com/a/2230/2018

Reply to comment:

No - it's not done that. I would install synaptic and then use that to search for the kde things you have installed. It's one of those jobs easier the second time, next time do it with a terminal and copy the output so you know what gets installed.

For instance

```
sudo apt-get install kde-full
```

get's these http://pastebin.com/QrYvxUf1

You might though find it easier and quicker to get the newest 12.04 daily and reinstall, you can use zsync to update your existing iso if you still have that.

Comment: Can you recommend a first course of action? does this mean I've screwed up my Ubuntu?

Comment: @AlexPoulos Having some extra packages around will not screw up your Ubuntu.  Look through the list of packages installed by the kde metapackages, see which ones you are *sure* you did not have before installing and remove them.

Answer (score 1):

FYI for future, check out Psychocats tutorials on installing/removing the different desktop environments.

http://psychocats.net/ubuntu/puregnome

The tutorials are only up through 11.10 (Oneric) currently as Precise isn't officially out yet but probably would work for 12.04 nonetheless.

Comment: I'd not assume packages between versions are the same - hence the various differing pages that are there

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This answer does not work. I am keeping it up simply to document this fact, because I honestly would have expected it to work.

I do not have `kubuntu-desktop` installed (slow Internet), but running `apt-get --dry-run autoremove ubuntu-desktop` only removes one package; I reason that `kubuntu-desktop` would behave similarly.

Props to @Chan-HoSuh and @NRoach44 for commenting persistently enough to make me actually *check* my answer.

---

Running `sudo apt-get autoremove kubuntu-desktop` should fix it. `autoremove` is the `apt-get` command to remove a packages *and* its dependencies.

It is possible that you must first reinstall `kubuntu-desktop` in order to autoremove it. APT should not, however, redownload the packages (downloaded packages are saved on your computer), but only reinstall them.

Comment: That only applies to regular packages.  *Meta*-packages like kubuntu-desktop are basically just wrappers and removing them will not usually remove all its dependencies (one notable exception is gnome-desktop).

Comment: 'command to remove packages **and** its **dependencies**' In that respect, meta packages are no different.

Comment: @NRoach44 The packages listed by the OP as still being installed after removal of `kubuntu-desktop` are listed as *dependencies* using `apt-cache showpkg` and also on the [package listing webpage](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/kubuntu-desktop) (in contrast to recommends).  Perhaps you're making some valid, technical point, but it must involve a definition of "dependency" that is not commonly used.

Comment: its okay guys, I went through and just reinstalled 12.04 anyway.

Comment: Just to clear it up, on Ubuntu server, if I install Thunderbird, it will install X.org and GTK etc... because Thunderbird needs (**depends** on) them. If I remove Thunderbird, GTK will not be removed because it does not depend on Thunderbird. If I remove X.org, GTK **and** Thunderbird will be removed because they depend on X.org. Your original post was correct that apt-get remove thunderbird would not remove (in this example) GTK or X.org. However, metapackages (as far as apt is concerned) are not different from normal ones, and thus autoremove would work with kubuntu-desktop.

Comment: @NRoach44 Have you actually tried this?  Countless people (including me) have tried what you are suggesting and `apt-get autoremove` simply does not remove the dependencies of `kubuntu-desktop`, `xubuntu-desktop`, etc.  The issue is that these metapackages mark their dependencies as manually installed so that autoremove will not remove them.  Not every metapackage does this (by reports, Gnome is particularly annoying about this).

Comment: Please see [this thread](http://askubuntu.com/q/37451/43660) for other people saying what I'm saying and a link to a website (psychocats) which I've seen linked time and time again to the same question of how to remove kubuntu, lubuntu, etc.  Note I'm not going to be responding further here (it's gotten long enough and I expect anybody reading this has been informed thoroughly)

Comment: I wouldn't have thought it, but the behaviour @Chan-HoSuh describes *is* what happens. Simply try `apt-get autoremove --dry-run ubuntu-desktop` on a vanilla install to verify.

Comment: @zpletan That does happen, however, the supporting packages are likely **not** marked as **automatically installed**, which is what autoremove services. From apt-get's CLI usage prompt: `autoremove - Remove automatically all unused packages`, unused being auto installed, and not depended on. I have used it in many similar situations, but I do not have the internet usage to test. What I am saying is from my experience, I do not dispute yours, but this is what **has** and **does** work for me.

Comment: I've removed kubuntu-desktop but its still showing in DE list on  login screen

Comment: @JeyKeu, per my edit two years ago, this answer does not work. Also per that edit, I left this answer up simply to document that it does not work. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Note, this applies only to Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise).

These removal commands were created based on what Kubuntu packages were added to a default Ubuntu installation. It's possible that the commands might remove some other packages you have since added to the default and want to keep. If that's the case, keep track of which packages those are and reinstall them. Theoretically, your settings should still be there.

```
sudo apt-get remove akonadi-backend-mysql akonadi-server akregator amarok amarok-common amarok-utils apport-kde apturl-kde ark bluedevil cdparanoia cdrdao cryptsetup docbook-xml docbook-xsl dolphin dragonplayer freespacenotifier gnupg-agent gnupg2 gpgsm gpsd gstreamer0.10-qapt gtk2-engines-oxygen gtk3-engines-oxygen gwenview ibus-qt4 icoutils jockey-kde k3b k3b-data kaccessible kaddressbook kamera kate kate-data katepart kcalc kde-baseapps-bin kde-baseapps-data kde-config-gtk kde-config-touchpad kde-runtime kde-runtime-data kde-style-oxygen kde-wallpapers-default kde-window-manager kde-window-manager-common kde-workspace kde-workspace-bin kde-workspace-data kde-workspace-kgreet-plugins kde-zeroconf kdegames-card-data kdegraphics-strigi-analyzer kdelibs-bin kdelibs5-data kdelibs5-plugins kdemultimedia-kio-plugins kdenetwork-filesharing kdepasswd kdepim-kresources kdepim-runtime kdepim-strigi-plugins kdepimlibs-kio-plugins kdesudo kdm kdoctools khelpcenter4 kinfocenter klipper kmag kmail kmenuedit kmix kmousetool knotes konsole kontact kopete kopete-message-indicator korganizer kpat kppp ksnapshot ksysguard ksysguardd ksystemlog ktimetracker ktorrent ktorrent-data kubuntu-debug-installer kubuntu-default-settings kubuntu-desktop kubuntu-docs kubuntu-firefox-installer kubuntu-netbook-default-settings kubuntu-notification-helper kubuntu-web-shortcuts kvkbd kwalletmanager language-selector-kde libakonadi-calendar4 libakonadi-contact4 libakonadi-kabc4 libakonadi-kcal4 libakonadi-kde4 libakonadi-kmime4 libakonadi-notes4 libakonadiprotocolinternals1 libassuan0 libattica0.3 libbluedevil1 libboost-program-options1.46.1 libcalendarsupport4 libcln6 libclucene0ldbl libdebconf-kde0 libdlrestrictions1 libdmtx0a libencode-locale-perl libepub0 libeventviews4 libfile-listing-perl libflac++6 libfont-afm-perl libgadu3 libgif4 libgpgme++2 libgps20 libgrantlee-core0 libhtml-form-perl libhtml-format-perl libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-tagset-perl libhtml-tree-perl libhttp-cookies-perl libhttp-daemon-perl libhttp-date-perl libhttp-message-perl libhttp-negotiate-perl libibus-qt1 libilmbase6 libincidenceeditorsng4 libindicate-qt1 libio-socket-inet6-perl libio-socket-ssl-perl libk3b6 libkabc4 libkactivities-bin libkactivities6 libkalarmcal2 libkateinterfaces4 libkatepartinterfaces4 libkblog4 libkcal4 libkcalcore4 libkcalutils4 libkcddb4 libkcmutils4 libkde3support4 libkdeclarative5 libkdecorations4 libkdecore5 libkdegames5a libkdepim4 libkdepimdbusinterfaces4 libkdesu5 libkdeui5 libkdewebkit5 libkdgantt2 libkdnssd4 libkemoticons4 libkephal4abi1 libkexiv2-10 libkexiv2-data libkfile4 libkholidays4 libkhtml5 libkidletime4 libkimap4 libkio5 libkipi-data libkipi8 libkjsapi4 libkjsembed4 libkldap4 libkleo4 libkmanagesieve4 libkmbox4 libkmediaplayer4 libkmime4 libknewstuff2-4 libknewstuff3-4 libknotifyconfig4 libkntlm4 libkonq-common libkonq5-templates libkonq5abi1 libkontactinterface4 libkopete4 libkparts4 libkpgp4 libkpimidentities4 libkpimtextedit4 libkpimutils4 libkprintutils4 libkpty4 libkresources4 libkrosscore4 libksba8 libkscreensaver5 libksgrd4 libksieve4 libksieveui4 libksignalplotter4 libktexteditor4 libktnef4 libktorrent-l10n libktorrent3 libkunitconversion4 libkwineffects1abi3 libkwinglutils1 libkwinnvidiahack4 libkworkspace4abi1 libkxmlrpcclient4 liblastfm0 libloudmouth1-0 liblwp-mediatypes-perl liblwp-protocol-https-perl libmailcommon4 libmailtools-perl libmailtransport4 libmessagecomposer4 libmessagecore4 libmessagelist4 libmessageviewer4 libmicroblog4 libmpcdec6 libmsn0.3 libmuonprivate1 libmygpo-qt1 libmysqlclient18 libnepomuk4 libnepomukdatamanagement4 libnepomukquery4a libnepomuksync4 libnepomukutils4 libnet-http-perl libnet-ssleay-perl libntrack-qt4-1 libntrack0 libokularcore1abi1 libopenexr6 libotr2 libphonon4 libplasma-geolocation-interface4 libplasma3 libplasmaclock4abi3 libplasmagenericshell4 libpolkit-qt-1-1 libpoppler-qt4-3 libprison0 libprocesscore4abi1 libprocessui4a libqalculate5 libqapt-runtime libqapt1 libqca2 libqca2-plugin-ossl libqgpgme1 libqimageblitz4 libqjson0 libqrencode3 libqt4-designer libqt4-help libqt4-qt3support libqt4-scripttools libqt4-sql-mysql libqt4-test libqtassistantclient4 libqtglib-2.0-0 libqtgstreamer-0.10-0 libqtscript4-core libqtscript4-gui libqtscript4-network libqtscript4-sql libqtscript4-uitools libqtscript4-xml libqtwebkit4 libreoffice-kde libreoffice-style-oxygen libsocket6-perl libsolid4 libsolidcontrol4abi2 libsolidcontrolifaces4abi2 libsoprano4 libstreamanalyzer0 libstreams0 libsyndication4 libtag-extras1 libtaskmanager4abi3 libtemplateparser4 libthreadweaver4 libtimedate-perl liburi-perl libvirtodbc0 libweather-ion6 libwww-perl libwww-robotrules-perl libxml2-utils libxss1 libzip2 muon muon-installer muon-notifier muon-updater mysql-client-core-5.5 mysql-common mysql-server-core-5.5 ntrack-module-libnl-0 odbcinst odbcinst1debian2 okular okular-extra-backends oxygen-cursor-theme oxygen-icon-theme partitionmanager phonon phonon-backend-gstreamer pinentry-gtk2 pinentry-qt4 plasma-dataengines-addons plasma-dataengines-workspace plasma-desktop plasma-netbook plasma-scriptengine-javascript plasma-scriptengine-python plasma-widget-facebook plasma-widget-folderview plasma-widget-kimpanel plasma-widget-menubar plasma-widget-message-indicator plasma-widget-networkmanagement plasma-widgets-addons plasma-widgets-workspace plymouth-theme-kubuntu-logo plymouth-theme-kubuntu-text polkit-kde-1 printer-applet python-kde4 python-pyudev python-qt4 python-qt4-dbus python-sip qapt-batch qapt-deb-installer quassel quassel-data rekonq sgml-data shared-desktop-ontologies software-properties-kde soprano-daemon system-config-printer-kde systemsettings tasks-icons update-manager-kde usb-creator-kde userconfig virtuoso-minimal virtuoso-opensource-6.1-bin virtuoso-opensource-6.1-common xsettings-kde && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

> **Source:** http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/pureubuntu

Comment: I did it and got this output:

Comment: based on your output, i suggest reviewing this duplicated question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/122242/how-do-i-remove-kubuntu-full-and-all-its-applications

Comment: Please attribute the source when you copy and paste -- I edited the original in, although you should so so even if you copied this from one of the two or three AU answers this is floating around in.

Answer (score 0):

Your question tells me that you want to **fully** uninstall Kubuntu and all of the applications it installs. Try this command:

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove akonadi-backend-mysql akonadi-server akregator amarok amarok-common amarok-utils apport-kde apturl-kde ark bluedevil cdparanoia cdrdao cryptsetup docbook-xml docbook-xsl dolphin dragonplayer freespacenotifier gnupg-agent gnupg2 gpgsm gpsd gstreamer0.10-qapt gtk2-engines-oxygen gtk3-engines-oxygen gwenview ibus-qt4 icoutils jockey-kde k3b k3b-data kaccessible kaddressbook kamera kate kate-data katepart kcalc kde-baseapps-bin kde-baseapps-data kde-config-gtk kde-config-touchpad kde-runtime kde-runtime-data kde-style-oxygen kde-wallpapers-default kde-window-manager kde-window-manager-common kde-workspace kde-workspace-bin kde-workspace-data kde-workspace-kgreet-plugins kde-zeroconf kdegames-card-data kdegraphics-strigi-analyzer kdelibs-bin kdelibs5-data kdelibs5-plugins kdemultimedia-kio-plugins kdenetwork-filesharing kdepasswd kdepim-kresources kdepim-runtime kdepim-strigi-plugins kdepimlibs-kio-plugins kdesudo kdm kdoctools khelpcenter4 kinfocenter klipper kmag kmail kmenuedit kmix kmousetool knotes konsole kontact kopete kopete-message-indicator korganizer kpat kppp ksnapshot ksysguard ksysguardd ksystemlog ktimetracker ktorrent ktorrent-data kubuntu-debug-installer kubuntu-default-settings kubuntu-desktop kubuntu-docs kubuntu-firefox-installer kubuntu-netbook-default-settings kubuntu-notification-helper kubuntu-web-shortcuts kvkbd kwalletmanager language-selector-kde libakonadi-calendar4 libakonadi-contact4 libakonadi-kabc4 libakonadi-kcal4 libakonadi-kde4 libakonadi-kmime4 libakonadi-notes4 libakonadiprotocolinternals1 libassuan0 libattica0.3 libbluedevil1 libboost-program-options1.46.1 libcalendarsupport4 libcln6 libclucene0ldbl libdebconf-kde0 libdlrestrictions1 libdmtx0a libencode-locale-perl libepub0 libeventviews4 libfile-listing-perl libflac++6 libfont-afm-perl libgadu3 libgif4 libgpgme++2 libgps20 libgrantlee-core0 libhtml-form-perl libhtml-format-perl libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-tagset-perl libhtml-tree-perl libhttp-cookies-perl libhttp-daemon-perl libhttp-date-perl libhttp-message-perl libhttp-negotiate-perl libibus-qt1 libilmbase6 libincidenceeditorsng4 libindicate-qt1 libio-socket-inet6-perl libio-socket-ssl-perl libk3b6 libkabc4 libkactivities-bin libkactivities6 libkalarmcal2 libkateinterfaces4 libkatepartinterfaces4 libkblog4 libkcal4 libkcalcore4 libkcalutils4 libkcddb4 libkcmutils4 libkde3support4 libkdeclarative5 libkdecorations4 libkdecore5 libkdegames5a libkdepim4 libkdepimdbusinterfaces4 libkdesu5 libkdeui5 libkdewebkit5 libkdgantt2 libkdnssd4 libkemoticons4 libkephal4abi1 libkexiv2-10 libkexiv2-data libkfile4 libkholidays4 libkhtml5 libkidletime4 libkimap4 libkio5 libkipi-data libkipi8 libkjsapi4 libkjsembed4 libkldap4 libkleo4 libkmanagesieve4 libkmbox4 libkmediaplayer4 libkmime4 libknewstuff2-4 libknewstuff3-4 libknotifyconfig4 libkntlm4 libkonq-common libkonq5-templates libkonq5abi1 libkontactinterface4 libkopete4 libkparts4 libkpgp4 libkpimidentities4 libkpimtextedit4 libkpimutils4 libkprintutils4 libkpty4 libkresources4 libkrosscore4 libksba8 libkscreensaver5 libksgrd4 libksieve4 libksieveui4 libksignalplotter4 libktexteditor4 libktnef4 libktorrent-l10n libktorrent3 libkunitconversion4 libkwineffects1abi3 libkwinglutils1 libkwinnvidiahack4 libkworkspace4abi1 libkxmlrpcclient4 liblastfm0 libloudmouth1-0 liblwp-mediatypes-perl liblwp-protocol-https-perl libmailcommon4 libmailtools-perl libmailtransport4 libmessagecomposer4 libmessagecore4 libmessagelist4 libmessageviewer4 libmicroblog4 libmpcdec6 libmsn0.3 libmuonprivate1 libmygpo-qt1 libmysqlclient18 libnepomuk4 libnepomukdatamanagement4 libnepomukquery4a libnepomuksync4 libnepomukutils4 libnet-http-perl libnet-ssleay-perl libntrack-qt4-1 libntrack0 libokularcore1abi1 libopenexr6 libotr2 libphonon4 libplasma-geolocation-interface4 libplasma3 libplasmaclock4abi3 libplasmagenericshell4 libpolkit-qt-1-1 libpoppler-qt4-3 libprison0 libprocesscore4abi1 libprocessui4a libqalculate5 libqapt-runtime libqapt1 libqca2 libqca2-plugin-ossl libqgpgme1 libqimageblitz4 libqjson0 libqrencode3 libqt4-designer libqt4-help libqt4-qt3support libqt4-scripttools libqt4-sql-mysql libqt4-test libqtassistantclient4 libqtglib-2.0-0 libqtgstreamer-0.10-0 libqtscript4-core libqtscript4-gui libqtscript4-network libqtscript4-sql libqtscript4-uitools libqtscript4-xml libqtwebkit4 libreoffice-kde libreoffice-style-oxygen libsocket6-perl libsolid4 libsolidcontrol4abi2 libsolidcontrolifaces4abi2 libsoprano4 libstreamanalyzer0 libstreams0 libsyndication4 libtag-extras1 libtaskmanager4abi3 libtemplateparser4 libthreadweaver4 libtimedate-perl liburi-perl libvirtodbc0 libweather-ion6 libwww-perl libwww-robotrules-perl libxml2-utils libxss1 libzip2 muon muon-installer muon-notifier muon-updater mysql-client-core-5.5 mysql-common mysql-server-core-5.5 ntrack-module-libnl-0 odbcinst odbcinst1debian2 okular okular-extra-backends oxygen-cursor-theme oxygen-icon-theme partitionmanager phonon phonon-backend-gstreamer pinentry-gtk2 pinentry-qt4 plasma-dataengines-addons plasma-dataengines-workspace plasma-desktop plasma-netbook plasma-scriptengine-javascript plasma-scriptengine-python plasma-widget-facebook plasma-widget-folderview plasma-widget-kimpanel plasma-widget-menubar plasma-widget-message-indicator plasma-widget-networkmanagement plasma-widgets-addons plasma-widgets-workspace plymouth-theme-kubuntu-logo plymouth-theme-kubuntu-text polkit-kde-1 printer-applet python-kde4 python-pyudev python-qt4 python-qt4-dbus python-sip qapt-batch qapt-deb-installer quassel quassel-data rekonq sgml-data shared-desktop-ontologies software-properties-kde soprano-daemon system-config-printer-kde systemsettings tasks-icons update-manager-kde usb-creator-kde userconfig virtuoso-minimal virtuoso-opensource-6.1-bin virtuoso-opensource-6.1-common xsettings-kde kubuntu-desktop sddm
```

After doing that, locate and delete remaining folders/files with this command:

```
find / -iname 'kde*' -iname 'sddm*' -iname 'kubuntu*' -delete
```

**Safety precaution: Before you delete all of these files, run the command without "-delete" and make sure you're comfortable with deleting these files.**