# Ubuntu Stopped Working After Uninstalling Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu

After installing Ubuntu on my laptop, I installed Kubuntu to see what it is like. I preferred Ubuntu, so I uninstalled Kubuntu using these instructions https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PureGnome. During the uninstallation terminal said that I need to stop a KDE deamon and I clicked yes and it closed my desktop and  put me in tty1 (I think). Since I didn't know what was happening and nothing seemed to be changing, I force shut down the laptop. Now when I start it it is forever on the loading screen. I've tried to reinstall using a disc, but that won't load either. I am new to linux/ubuntu and have no idea how to do things.

Comment: **Possible Duplicate** of   [How do I remove Kubuntu-full and all it's applications][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/122242/how-do-i-remove-kubuntu-full-and-all-its-applications

Answer (score 1):

1. When booted, choose "recovery mode".
2. From the boot menu, open a terminal, and type the following command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
   ```
3. Then, to update the resource lists and remove redundant packages, run the commands below:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get autoremove
   sudo apt-get check
   sudo apt-get clean
   sudo apt-get autoclean
   ```