# How to completely remove the kubuntu-desktop?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, uninstall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I remove kubuntu-full and all it's applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122242/how-do-i-remove-kubuntu-full-and-all-its-applications)

I installed the kubuntu-desktop on Ubuntu 12.04. I promptly removed it, the applications it installed are still there but that's not matter. But I can still choose Kubuntu Plasma Desktop during login. Clearly I haven't removed it completely. I went to the Ubuntu Software Centre and removed it from there. Then I did the removal process from [here](http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Install-KDE-SC-4-8-on-Ubuntu-11-10-248829.shtml). I did:

`sudo apt-get install -y ppa-purge`

`sudo ppa-purge ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports`

`sudo apt-get -f -y autoremove`

Still there. How do I remove it completely? Thanks.

UPDATE: @xlukask

I did the command and got this output:

```
 Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package ktorrent is not installed, so not removed
Package ktorrent-data is not installed, so not removed
Package kubuntu-desktop is not installed, so not removed
Package libktorrent-l10n is not installed, so not removed
Package libktorrent3 is not installed, so not removed
Package plymouth-theme-kubuntu-logo is not installed, so not removed
Package plymouth-theme-kubuntu-text is not installed, so not removed
Package dolphin is not installed, so not removed
Package ktimetracker is not installed, so not removed
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 icedtea-netx : Depends: openjdk-6-jre (>= 6b23~pre10~) but it is not going to be installed or
                         openjdk-7-jre but it is not going to be installed
 libatk-wrapper-java : Depends: default-jre but it is not going to be installed or
                                java2-runtime
 libatk-wrapper-java-jni : Depends: default-jre but it is not going to be installed or
                                    java2-runtime
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```